# Click handler not working

Tags: jquery

I've got a few buttons with the class `PhotoUploadSubmit`, and when a button is clicked, a custom click handler is used to look at sibling elements, etc.  The click handler doesn't work, `debugger` never goes off, breakpoints are not hit, and I'm totally baffled.

```
<div class="formDataContext">
    <input type="file" name="ImageData" style="display:none" />
    <button class="PhotoUploadSubmit"><i class="fa fa-camera fa-5x"></i></button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $(".PhotoUploadSubmit").on("click", function () {
        debugger;
        var currentFormDataContext = $(this).closest(".formDataContext");
        console.log(currentFormDataContext);
        var FileInput = currentFormDataContext.find("input:file")[0];
        console.log(FileInput);
        $(FileInput).click();
    });

    $("input:file").change(function () {
        var currentFormDataContext = $(this).closest(".formDataContext");
        uploadImage(currentFormDataContext);
    });
});

</script>
```

In terms of what I've tried, I've tried putting the click handler outside of `document.ready`, I've tried using the `debugger;` keyword, and I've tried setting breakpoints.  There's no console errors.

Comment: Did you include jquery.js on the page?

Comment: Is the button dynamically added to your page ?

Comment: @AlienWebguy Yeah, jQuery is included and everything else is working fine.

Comment: @FlorianF. The buttons are dynamically added to the page via Knockout.JS

Comment: `$(".formDataContext").on("click",".PhotoUploadSubmit" function ()  { });`

Comment: @alex Then void's answer is the right one, you need to use delegates, ask him for more explanation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `buttons` are dynamically added so you can [**delegate**](http://sitepoint.com/event-delegation-with-jquery). Example:

```
$("body").on("click", '.PhotoUploadSubmit', function () {
    debugger;
    var currentFormDataContext = $(this).closest(".formDataContext");
    console.log(currentFormDataContext);
    var FileInput = currentFormDataContext.find("input:file")[0];
    console.log(FileInput);
    $(FileInput).click();
});
```

Comment: Using this solved the problem.  I wasn't considering that the buttons were dynamically rendered.  I didn't think it would make a difference because the click handlers fired after `document.ready`!

Comment: Some more explanations about delegates and especially event bubbling mechanism would have been cool. "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime"

Comment: More about delegate:


  http://www.sitepoint.com/event-delegation-with-jquery/